# Warning in php with csv

Tags: php, csv

this is my code

```
<?php 
ini_set("display_errors", true); 
$inputFilename = 'HW8.csv'; 
$outputFilename = 'HW8.xml'; 

// Open csv to read 
$inputFile = fopen($inputFilename, 'rt'); 

// Get the headers of the file 
$headers = fgetcsv($inputFile); 

// Create a new dom document with pretty formatting 
$doc = new DomDocument(); 
$doc->formatOutput = true; 

// Add a root node to the document 
$root = $doc->createElement('rows'); 
$root = $doc->appendChild($root); 

// Loop through each row creating a <row> node with the correct data 
while (($row = fgetcsv($inputFile)) !== FALSE) 
{ 
 $container = $doc->createElement('row'); 

 // $i is the array index (0,1,2,..) and $header is the value at $i 
 foreach ($headers as $i => $header) 
 { 
 $child = $doc->createElement($header); 
 $child = $container->appendChild($child); 
 $value = $doc->createTextNode($row[$i]); 
 $value = $child->appendChild($value); 
 } 

 $root->appendChild($container); 
} 


echo $doc->saveXML();
```

and i got this warning
Warning: fopen(input2.csv) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /users/csegrad/csv.php on line 9

Warning: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /users/csegrad/csv.php on line 12

Warning: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /users/csegrad/csv.php on line 23

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /users/csegrad/csv.php on line 28

Comment: The error is pretty clear; either the file isn't where you're telling the fopen() function that it is, or your script doesn't have permission to read it

Comment: What is that read mode `rt`?, is that supposed to be `r+`?